# Condition between two radio buttons

Tags: jquery, if-statement, radio-button

I am trying to implement a menu that loads the next questions based on the users input.

I am able to implement it to a certain extent, but am struggling with being able to say:

```
if (item1.val() === 'veterans' && item2.val() === 'yes') {
    do something
}
```

I am doing this in jsbin, too much code for here: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qagile/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value for your second question is "current-yes" and not just "yes".

Besides that, you have to get the value of the radio button that is checked. Right now, you are always getting the first radio's value.

So try to change your condition to:

```
if ($('input[type=radio][name=interested]:checked').val() === 'veterans' && $('input[type=radio][name=current]:checked').val() === 'current-yes') {
  $('#customer-information').show();
} else {
  $('#stepThree').show();
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, good catch. It is loading the customer-information div automatically when I click on the "Are you interested in".